# Inline elements CSS

Tags: css

I want a navigation like structure in the header of my page, so I decided I'd use an inline list however the result it is producing is not what I imagined. It is placing the elements on 3 separate lines.

```
Element 1    Element 2    Element 3
```

The above is what I am aiming to achieve, however currently I get,

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
```

This is my CSS and HTML snippets:

CSS

```
#nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><button id="left_nav"><</button></li>
    <li><div id="day">Monday</div></li>
    <li><button id="right_nav">></button></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS you're using?

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline`?

Comment: We need to see your HTML/CSS

Comment: @ExplosionPills so how would I then center the middle element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline-block instead of inline, you can also use this by float...

By **Inline-block**,

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By **Float**,

```
#nav {
      overflow:hidden;
}
#nav li {
      float:left; margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, how can I separately modify position of elements now? I've floated elements inside the li but still no movement.

Comment: is the size of container where ul is there is lesser than the size you want...? see the edit i made...

Comment: how would I center the middle element in the middle of the page?

Comment: Not working, after putting `text-align: center;` in the code for that element.

Comment: seems to be problem in center aligning with float... implement "display:inline-block;" and on "#nav" implement "text-align:center;" surely it will work...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS for your LI's...

```
li{ display:inline; }
```

Comment: I have that, it produces what I said it produces.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/znwhF/)

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` or `float:right`  aligns side by side

```
#nav li { 

float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `buttons` and `div` inside `li` give `width` to `div` and `button` that will work.

Because `div` is block level element and its use all the `width` of page if you not assign fixed width.

**OR**

apply `float: left;` to `li` that will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
#navigation ul
{margin:0px; padding:0px;}

#navigation ul li
{display:inline; height:30px; float:left; list-style:none; margin-left:15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure is different for different users.
Check the link: http://jsfiddle.net/wWyMW/1/

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <a href="#">Element <span>1</span></a>
           <div class="clr"></div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="#">Element <span>2</span></a>
           <div class="clr"></div>
       </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">Element <span>3</span></a>
           <div class="clr"></div>
       </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**And The CSS:**

```
*{ matgin:0; padding:0}
ul, li{ list-style:none}
a{ text-decoration:none}
.clr{ clear:both;}
#nav{margin:auto; width:960px;}
#nav ul li{ float:left; margin-left:10px}
#nav ul li:first-child{ margin-left:0}
#nav ul li a{ display:block; background:#f00; color:#0F0; line-height:30px; text-align:center; width:70px; padding:0px 10px; font-weight:bold;}
#nav ul li a span{ display:block; float:right;}
```